# mysql query ManyToMany Relation

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have three tables one is product and second is appliedFeaturesValue and third is appliedFeatures

In Product table appliedFeaturesValue have ManyToMany relation.

```
ProductID appliedFeaturesValueId
 1          1
 1          2
 2          1
 3          2
```

And in appliedFeaturesValue table have ManyToOne relation with appliedFeatures .

```
appliedFeaturesValue    appliedFeaturesId
    1                          70
    2                          88
```

I want to get product id 1 where both appliedFeaturesValue Id 1 and 2 are available behalf of appliedFeaturesId 70 and 88.

If I am using IN clause then not return exact product data where appliedFeaturesValue.id = 1 AND appliedFeaturesValue.id = 2.

If I am using AND clause then no result found.

This is my original query with AND clause where no result found:-

```
SELECT p0_ FROM Product p0_ INNER JOIN product_applied_features_value p2_ ON p0_.id = p2_.product_id INNER JOIN applied_features_value a1_ ON a1_.id = p2_.applied_features_value_id WHERE p0_.status = 1 AND a1_.applied_features_id = 70 AND a1_.applied_features_id = 88 ORDER BY p0_.id DESC
```

This is my query with IN clause :-

```
SELECT p0_ FROM Product p0_ INNER JOIN product_applied_features_value p2_ ON p0_.id = p2_.product_id INNER JOIN applied_features_value a1_ ON a1_.id = p2_.applied_features_value_id WHERE p0_.status = 1 AND a1_.applied_features_id IN (70,88) ORDER BY p0_.id DESC
```

How I will get exact matching record ??

Comment: Can you create an example of schema with some test data [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/) and specify desirable output?

Answer (score 0):

Try the below query, which can help you.

```
SELECT product.* FROM Product product 
INNER JOIN product_applied_features_value prodAppFeatures ON product.appliedFeaturesValueId = prodAppFeatures.id
INNER JOIN applied_features_value appFeatures ON appFeatures.id = prodAppFeatures.applied_features_value_id 
WHERE product.status = 1 AND 
    appFeatures.applied_features_id = 70 AND a1_.applied_features_id = 88 ORDER BY product.id DESC
```